# Python Option Parser: Boolean flag with optional parameters

Tags: python, parameter-passing, command-line-arguments, optional-parameters

I'm using optparse.OptionParser to manage arguments for some scripts, and something I was wondering / would like to do is have boolean flags (i.e `action=store_true`) that can also accept a parameter.

To put this into context, I've got a application that can use as many GPU/Processors as it finds on the machine. For a variety of reasons sometimes you want to limit the number of devices it uses, and instead of further cluttering the command line, I'd like to be able to:

```
script -c -g
```

meaning use all you can of all cpus and gpus, and

```
script -c 2 -g 3
```

meaning limit the script execution to 2 CPUs and 3 GPUs.

After reading the optparse documentation, I'm none the wiser. Oh great SO gurus! Lend me your wisdom!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `callback` action to implement this quite easily. In particular, [example 6 in the documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html#callback-example-6-variable-arguments) of the callback action of `OptionParser` discusses a variable number of arguments. Here's a telling quote from that example:

> Things get hairy when you want an
>   option to take a variable number of
>   arguments. For this case, you must
>   write a callback, as optparse doesn’t
>   provide any built-in capabilities for
>   it.

Comment: Thanks Eli, saw that but was hoping for something cleaner for the corner case of 'I'm either boolean or an argument'

Comment: @Andrew: I see it rather as "either 0 or 1 arguments"

Comment: As close to an answer as practical. Thanks @Eli